# Why the actor neural network is not learning?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, actor, training-data

Good evening,

the code shown below represents the training function of an actor network. The idea is to use it in a cycle to control a system. All the control actions are generated by this
neural network and they should converge to the values proposed by the Cross Entropy Method, that minimizes a cost. The latter is approximated by a critic neural network that seems to work well.

While the system is runing, the Cross Entropy Method function returns convincing values but the actor continues to increase the control action, augmenting the error.

What could be the problem?

'''

## Code

#Input data are normalized

def Actor_train(state_train, action_train, force_train, Actor_NN, Critic_NN, Model_NN, xdh_intro, Kh, xy_norm, Nh, learning_rate):

```
#action_mean_, action_std_ = action_norm
#fh_mean_, fh_std_ = fh_norm

Actor_NN_ = Actor_NN
Critic_NN_ = Critic_NN
Model_NN_ = Model_NN
Nh_ = Nh
learning_rate_ = learning_rate
xy_norm_ = xy_norm

x_mean_v_, x_std_v_, y_mean_v_, y_std_v_ = xy_norm_ #variables to normalize
state_not_norm_ = state_train*x_std_v_[0:2] + x_mean_v_[0:2] #denormalization

# normalized quantities
state_train_ = np.copy(state_train[0:Nh_,:])
action_train_ = Variable(torch.from_numpy(action_train[0:Nh_].squeeze(1)), requires_grad=True)
# action_train comes from a neural network
force_train_ = np.copy(force_train[0:Nh_])

Actor_NN_.to("cpu")  # putting the model into GPU (but not available now)
optimizer_A = torch.optim.Adam(Actor_NN_.get_parameters(), lr =learning_rate_)
errore_f = nn.MSELoss()

cache_loss_ = []
resultant_loss_ = []
iteration_ = 0
    
for j in range(0, Nh_-1):
    
    Actor_NN.train()
    optimizer_A.zero_grad()
    # Cross entropy method to estimate u minimizing the output of the critic network
    U_npiu1 = CEM_critic(state_not_norm_[j:j+1], 1, 5, 64, xy_norm_, Cost_norm, Model_NN,
                         critic, xdh_intro, Kh, num_ensembles_cem_= 5)[0]
    
    action_from_NN = torch.DoubleTensor(action_train_[j+1:j+2])
    action_from_CEM = torch.DoubleTensor(U_npiu1)[0]
    print("NN ", action_from_NN[0])
    print("CEM ", action_from_CEM)
    # Cost function
    Error_a = errore_f.forward(action_from_NN[0], action_from_CEM)
    Error_a.backward(retain_graph=True)                           # backprop
    optimizer_A.step()                             # updating the parameters
    Nh_loss_ = Error_a
    # torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    cache_loss_.append(Nh_loss_.item())
    iteration_ =+1
    
    if (j+1)%2 ==0:
        resultant_ = np.sum(cache_loss_)/iteration_
        resultant_loss_.append(resultant_)
        iteration_ = 0
        cache_loss_ =[]
        print("epoch:",j+1," Actor Training_loss:", resultant_)
        


plt.plot(resultant_loss_,'r')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.xlabel('epochs')
plt.title('actor')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

print("Final training loss: ",resultant_loss_[-1])    

return
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you wanted `iteration_ += 1` instead of what you have: `iteration_ =+1`

Comment: Yes, thank you. Anyway it enters only in the visual output and doesn't affect the calculation of the gradient and the update, so there should be another problem